# Undefined offset error, form, pdo, php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, submit

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/contactdb/add-job-bork.php on line 34
```

I am getting the above error and data is failing to reach the database. I tried isset but no luck

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "custdb";
$pass = "";
$db = "accounting";
session_start();

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//insert job
if (isset($_POST['invoice_num'])) {
        $cust_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $date_order = $_POST['date_order'];
        $invoice_num = $_POST['invoice_num'];

        $q = "INSERT INTO orders (cust_id,date_order, invoice_num)
                        SELECT * FROM (SELECT :cust_id,:date_order, invoice_num) as tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT invoice_num FROM orders WHERE invoice_num = :invoice_num)
        LIMIT 1;";

        $query = $odb->prepare($q);
        $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":cust_id" => $cust_id,
        ":date_order" => $date_order,
        ":invoice_num" => $invoice_num
        ));
}
?>

<?php
$cust_info = $_SESSION['id'];
$pieces = explode(":", $cust_info);
$_SESSION['id'] = $pieces[0];
if (isset($pieces[1])) {
        $_SESSION['cust_name'] = $pieces[1];
}


?>
        <div class="">
                <form method="post" action"">
                        <label> Order date:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="date_order" name="date_order"/> <br />
                        <input type="text" id="invoice_num" name="invoice_num"/> <br />
                        <input type ="submit" value"Submit" /> <br /> <br />
                </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($pieces);`?

Comment: How did you try `isset()` function?

Comment: @hjpotter92   array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" }     It appears to be missing half of it's data.

Comment: I mean you should check if `$pieces[1]` exists with `isset($pieces[1])`.

Comment: @barell if (isset($pieces[1])) {
        $_SESSION['cust_name'] = $pieces[1];
}
addressed the error, but still no data in the database. the sql worked fine before I started working with the $_SESSION. I borked something but just can't find it.

Comment: Is there any place in the code where you're joining id and name with `:` and storing it in `$_SESSION['id']`? And the second question is, why don't you store different data in different session values?

Comment: @barell  yes ->  http://bpaste.net/show/184805/  line 42. I could only get 1 element through the value='$_POST' hole, so I glued them together with .":". and then on the ^^ above page I explode() them apart from their delimiter on line 4 here ->  http://bpaste.net/show/184807/  (full code of the above), then use the 2 values elsewhere in the code stored as $_SESSION['id'] and $_SESSION['cust_name']

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48908/discussion-between-barell-and-brad)

Comment: @brad place the start of a session on the first line of a PHP script. `session_start();`

Comment: @Mr. Radical it is there. if you check the chat session, there is much more detail.

Comment: @brad I checked the chat. I didn't see `session_start();` on the first line in any of your screenshots. Place it directly under `<?php`. I copied your code on my local server install and it didn't give me any trouble.

Comment: @Mr. Radical the full code is on the bpaste.net/~ 's on the chat, it already is first. The code fails to actually enter data into the database. I am really sure it's what is in the image is the issue. I could be wrong.